# Applying simple mathematical function on numbers extracted with regex

Tags: r, regex

I am wondering how I can perform basic mathematical manipulation on numbers that are in the string? For example, imagine I have a data frame like this:

```
structure(list(Commission20 = c("$3255 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE", 
"$3255 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE", "$1", "1ST $100000 2.5% AND BALANCE 1.2%", 
"3.3% AND 1.0%ST $100 - 1.2% BALANCE", "3 % 1ST $100000 AND 1.0% SALE BALANCE"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Commission20                         
  <chr>                                
1 $3255 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE   
2 $3255 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE   
3 $1                                   
4 1ST $100000 2.5% AND BALANCE 1.2%    
5 3.3% AND 1.0%ST $100 - 1.2% BALANCE  
6 3 % 1ST $100000 AND 1.0% SALE BALANCE
```

The standard form of Commission is `a.b% 1ST $abcdef AND m.n% BALANCE` where `a.b%` is a number like 3.3%, `$abcdef` is a number like $100000 and `m.n%` a number like 1.2%. As it can be seen in this data frame, `$3255 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE` is not in the standard form. So my goal is to change **only** commission in the form of `$klmn 1ST $abcdef AND m.n% BALANCE` to the standard form. The way I should do it is to divide `klmn/abcdef`. so for instance a string like :

`$3255 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE`  should be replaced by `3.2% 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE` where 3.2% is calculated from 3255/100000.

How can I do this? I am not sure what function gives the possibility to me to not only select those two numbers but also divide them. So the above data frame should be changed to:

```
1 3.2% 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE   
2 3.2% 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE   
3 $1                                   
4 1ST $100000 2.5% AND BALANCE 1.2%    
5 3.3% AND 1.0%ST $100 - 1.2% BALANCE  
6 3 % 1ST $100000 AND 1.0% SALE BALANCE
```

**Changes only applied to row 1 and row 2** because only row 1 and row 2 match `$klmn 1ST $abcdef AND m.n% BALANCE` pattern hence they should be changed to `a.b% 1ST $abcdef AND m.n% BALANCE` pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stringr`'s `str_replace_all` which accepts a function to be applied to a matched pattern.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(df$Commission20, '\\$\\d+ 1ST \\$\\d+', function(m) {
  m1 <- as.numeric(sub('\\$(\\d+).*', '\\1', m))
  m2 <- as.numeric(sub('.*\\$(\\d+)$', '\\1', m))
  sub('\\$\\w+', paste0(m1/m2 * 100, '%'), m)
})

#[1] "3.255% 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE"   "3.255% 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE"  
#[3] "$1"                                    "1ST $100000 2.5% AND BALANCE 1.2%"    
#[5] "3.3% AND 1.0%ST $100 - 1.2% BALANCE"   "3 % 1ST $100000 AND 1.0% SALE BALANCE"
```

`\\$\\d+ 1ST \\$\\d+` is used to identify rows to which we want to apply the function to.

`m1` is the first number in the extracted pattern (`3255`)

`m2` is the last number in the extracted pattern (`100000`)

We use `sub` to replace only the first word in the string after performing the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, Ronak Shah. I just have one question. Using a function inside `str_replace_all` made me confused. Can you elaborate more on how it's working? what does the function return as a replacement? 
Also, Since I prefer dealing with the main data frame, is there any way to get the output as data frame? should I simply use `as.dataframe`?

Comment: `'\\$\\d+ 1ST \\$\\d+'` is input in replacement function and `sub('\\$\\w+', paste0(m1/m2 * 100, '%'), m)` is output. You can assign data back to column to maintain the dataframe. `df$Commission20 <- stringr::str_replace_all(df$Commission20, ....)`